# How we can achieve HMC customisation?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

In *Hmc.xml* we can do it but don't know how so, please give some examples and if any other ways are there to **customise HMC** please explain.

Comment: There are documentation to read... Please come back if you have a programming issue and if you're able to provide some code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the examples you need, you can find in the current system hmc.xml files. In general you can have a hmc.xml for each of your extensions and during build,they are all appended to the main hmc.xml. If you don't want to build and start the server every time, in your `hmc->System->hmc configuration` you can find the currently used xml and also can modify it and save. After that you are logged out and when you login again, you can see your changes. Here is some documentation [Hybris Wiki](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/Configuring+the+hMC+Interface)